# use an array of strings to generate every possible combination with a constant

Tags: java

given a string array

```
String[] values = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
```

and a constant

```
 final String X = "X";
```

Generate every possible way the value array can contain 0 or more X

i.e

```
    [A, B, C, D, E]
    [A, X, X, D, E]
    [A, B, X, D, E]
    [X, X, X, X, X]
```

and so on with every possibility. Needs to be fast - bit of a brain teaser i'm having trouble making efficient. Not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: Hint: all possible combinations can be represented by a 5-digit binary string from 00000 (all of the original values) to 11111 (all X). To get from 00000 to 11111 you simply add 1 to the binary number represented by that bit pattern until you reach (or exceed) 11111.

Comment: Let's see the code that you are _having trouble making efficient_.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, that was very helpful. I was trying to solve it with recursion and it wasn't working out.

Comment: Sorry Beau - my example here was a simplified version of a problem i'm trying to solve using much larger sets of data of various sizes. All I needed was to figure out this little brain teaser which Joachim's comment worked for. I'll post the solution's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was in Joachim Sauer's hint:

```
      String[] values = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    final String ONE = "1";
    final String X = "X";
    int control=0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(values.length);
    String copy[];
    int count = Integer.parseInt(new String(new char[values.length]).replace("\0", ONE), 2) ;
    while (control <= count) {
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        sb.append(String.format("%" + values.length  + "s", Integer.toBinaryString(control++)).replace(' ', '0'));
        copy = values.clone();
        for (int x = 0; x < sb.length(); x ++) {
            if (sb.substring(x, x+1).equals(ONE)) {
                copy[x] = X;
            }
        }
       System.out.println(control + " " + Arrays.toString(copy));
       map.put(generateHashCode(copy),copy.clone());
    }


    System.out.println(map.values().size());
```